# How could Muhammad have interpreted and taught the Quran?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad

I'm just beginning to learn about the Islamic religion, I was reading about the Quran and I read that it is not believed to have been written by any person, but given to humans by God. From what I understand it was found by the prophet Muhammad and he interpreted it and taught others. The fact that the Quran was a devine gift from Allah is defended by the fact that Muhammad was illiterate and had never been to school. So I don't understand how he then found it, followed it's teachings, and taught others about the Quran? I think I'm missing a piece of the puzzle because I don't understand how an illiterate man read and followed the teachings of the Quran? 
Thank you for your help in answering my question.

Comment: You are missing a tiny piece in this puzzle: Angel Gabriel came and taught Muhammad Quran.  [Also in Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad%27s_first_revelation)

Comment: Muhammed (peace be upon him) himself "was taught" the Quran "piecewise" by the Angel Gabriel (peace be upon him) and each Ramadan he was tested by him at least once to get sure whether he remembered what he has been taught so far. But Muhammad had scribes who used to write down each revelation http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28370/prophet-muhammad-saw-was-illiterate-who-wrote-the-quran-then/28371?s=8|2.1109#28371

Answer (score 3):

- Yes, the Prophet(PBUH) was illiterate, meaning he couldn't read or write. It doesn't say he was not intelligent or lacked the ability to understand and interpret.
- The Quran was taught to Prophet by Angel Gabriel in parts. This [link](http://www.missionislam.com/quran/revealationorder.htm) explains better.

"The Qur'an was sometimes revealed to respond to various events and incidents. Sometimes it was revealed to support the Prophet (saws) who was faced with many questions, whether by Muslims or non-Muslims, and hardships. Other times was revealed for legislation and for putting rules to govern the social, economical, and political life of Muslims."

- Another piece of puzzle you are missing here is that it was the Companions of the Prophet who memorized the verses of Quran and later compiled it into the form you see today. But nobody else on the planet had a better understanding of the Quran other the Prophet.
- The biggest miracle of Islam is the Quran. No scholar was able to reproduce anything close to the verses of the Quran. Not then and not ever.