# Is it true that the Prophet Mohamed said he inspired himself from the Apostles of Jesus-Christ?

Tags: practical-islam, prophet-muhammad, history, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

I read a few years ago a translation of the Coran very near the text and done by a serious author. I read:

> "The prophet Mohamed inspired himself from the teaching of the
>   Apostles of Jerusalem, the Apostles of Jesus-Christ (...) I read also
>   that the Coran was not written for 200 years and after it was written
>   on banana leafs and on mud tablets."

Plants were used in the fabrication of paper and mud tablets were found in Mesopotamia. My intend is friendship and my goal is to learn more and better and to show others how to talk publicly about religions to appease violence. 
 It is a skill to learn how to talk publicly about religions, philosophies and esoterisms (rare private philosophies). I have a bachelor's degree in theology from Laval University's faculty of theology and of sciences of religion.
 I tried many times in San Jose, Ca, USA (asked by others and supported by others, always) to appease tensions and violence explaining in public how a human being function and how his or her religion affect his or her way of thinking. It works great every single time.

Comment: I tried to be the most respectful to islam asking my question. I don't know if I am allowd to mention the name of the Prophet publicly; but I did not reproduct his image and/or the image of God.

Comment: I truly believe that Mahomed is a Prophet that had a message to give to the world coming from the Creator: God is one. Christians, including Catholics often forget that God, the Creator of the universe, is One. Is is a Grace that is a blessing for our current time; plus their (of Muslim faithful) example of prayer when many Christians pray less and less, still.

Comment: I am not makig money with this question or those comments. I am not paid. It is a personal gesture based on my roman catholic baptism that ask me to transform our world in less suffering and more peace.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome. As long as you don't blaspheme you need not fear, no one is going to hurt you (God willing). I'm glad you realized the Father(Creator) is one.

**No, *it is not at all true*** that Prophet Mohamed said he inspired himself from the Apostles of Jesus-Christ This is a common question which newbies have. Better get started with [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quran) and other *related questions* appearing on your right side in this page. See [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/30287/9123) for a brief overview of how the **Qur'an was inspired to Prophet Muhammad through [Angel Gabriel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel).**

Feel free to ask any more questions you have here, but only after enough research.

God knows the best.

Answer (score 0):

[Karen Armstrong](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Armstrong) is a well-known author on comparative religion; and a former Roman Catholic nun and has written several books on Islam, including *Muhammed: a prophet for our time*.

In [this](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2006/dec/23/religion.christmas) short article she points out the Gospel of Luke is consistent with Islamic tradition as he calls Jesus a prophet, and also that

> the Qu'ran insists that all rightly guided religions come from God, and that Muslims are required to believe in the revelations of each and every single one of Gods messengers: Abraham and Ishmael and Isaac and Jacob...and all the other prophets: we make no distinction between any of them (3:84)

Muhammed was directly inspired by the Angel Gabriel, but the prophet Isa Ibn Maryam or Jesus is honoured in the Qu'ran as one of the greatest of prophets, with Ibn Arabi, the Andalusian mystic calling him the seal of saints in what looks like a deliberate parallel with Muhammed called the seal of prophets.