# Historical evidence for literacy or illiteracy of Muhammad?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

I'm reading Quran and I'm also learning Arabic in an attempt to read Quran first-hand, without being dependent upon translations.

Recently I encountered the verse [29:48](https://quran.com/29/48), and realized that Quran emphasizes the illiteracy of Muhammad, but relates it to the past (مِن قَبْلِهِۦ). I don't understand past of what.

From verse [96:1](https://quran.com/96/1), I assume that it's related to before receiving revelations from Allah.

However, [in this argument](https://qr.ae/pNVYdj), it's strongly supported that Muhammad knew how to read and write. Partly because he was a merchant and we didn't have numeral systems around in those days and he had to use characters to count.

What historical evidences, other than Islamic books, do we have for literacy/illiteracy of Muhammad?

Comment: related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/did-prophet-muhammad-know-learn-how-to-write

Comment: Thank you. But as I mentioned, I need evidance outside the Islamic books.

Comment: You do understand that biographies about the Prophet (SAW) only come from Islamic sources right? You aren't going to find detailed description of the Prophet (SAW) outside them.

Comment: We have epigraphs related to some kings. We have paintings and palaces of some historical figures. We have trace of some people in the history of other nations. Do we have something similar for him?